# probability of even numbers in n tries of coin flip

Tags: probability, summation

ive came across a problem in my probability class where they ask to find the probability of getting an even number of heads within n tries. They also added the fact that n is even. 
I tried the binomial with Newtons law but i get 1 instead of $1/2$ 
this is what i try to solve

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{2k} \left({\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{2k} \left({\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{n-2k}$$

is this good ?

Comment: It's a good start. You can simplify ${\frac{1}{2}}^{2k} {\frac{1}{2}}^{n-2k}$.

Comment: @Arthur I did and then I got $(\frac{1}{2})^n \sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{2k}$. Then I try and index shift i give $2k=r$ and it gives me $ (\frac{1}{2})^n \sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}$ which gives me $2^n • (\frac{1}{2})^n$

Comment: It's not $\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} = 2^n$, it's $$\sum_{r=0\\r\text{ even}}^n \binom{n}{r}$$which is a bit less.

Comment: @Arthur so it has to be something like $\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{r}$ ?

Comment: No. $\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r} = \binom n0 + \binom n1 + \binom n2 + \cdots + \binom n{n-1} + \binom nn$. On the other hand, $\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\binom nr = \binom n0 + \binom n1 + \binom n2 \cdots + \binom n{n-2} + \binom n{n-1}$. What you want, however, is $\binom n0 + \binom n2 + \binom n4 + \cdots + \binom n{n-2} + \binom nn$, which is quite different.

Comment: @Arthur true but didnt i already divided n by 2 in the starting function thus : $$\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{2k} ({\frac{1}{2}})^{2k} ({\frac{1}{2}})^{n-2k}$$ or am i just going in circles

Comment: Exactly what index you use is not really that important. What's important is that you get the right terms. $\sum_{r = 0}^n$ and $\sum_{r = 0}^{n-1}$ do not give you the right terms.

Comment: @Arthur oh ok so do i add up even numbers using what i have or what does it give us ?

Comment: @Arthur i ment to ask  *how*do i add up

Comment: That's what the hint in my answer is about. Why did you accept that if you didn't get it?

Comment: @arthur i dont understand what u mean by why i accepted ur answer before getting it

Comment: The green check mark you clicked to the left of my answer. It means you've accepted my answer. If you don't understand what it says, you should've written a comment under it. When you check the "accepted" mark, that signals that you've understood the answer and that it's been helpful.

Comment: @Arthur ohhh ok im sorry im new to forums i wanted to somehow "like" if we could say ur answer but i discovered the up button :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to elaborate on the slick hint of @Arthur, because the OP seems confused in the comments: Since $(-1)^k=-1$ if $k$ is odd and $(-1)^k=1$ if $k$ is even, you have:
\begin{align}0=(1+(-1))^n=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\dbinom{n}{k}&=\sum_{k\text{ even}}\dbinom{n}{k}-\sum_{k\text{ odd}}\dbinom{n}{k}\\[0.2cm]2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{k=1}^n\dbinom{n}{k}&=\sum_{k\text{ even}}\dbinom{n}{k}+\sum_{k\text{ odd}}\dbinom{n}{k}\end{align} Hence, adding these two you get: $$2^n+0=\sum_{k\text{ even}}\dbinom{n}{k}+\sum_{k\text{ odd}}\dbinom{n}{k}+\sum_{k\text{ even}}\dbinom{n}{k}-\sum_{k\text{ odd}}\dbinom{n}{k}=2\sum_{k\text{ even}}\dbinom{n}{k}$$ which implies that $$2^n=2\sum_{k\text{ even}}\dbinom{n}{k} \implies \sum_{k\text{ even}}\dbinom{n}{k}=2^{n-1}$$ Hence $$\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\dbinom{n}{2k}=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k\text{ even}}\dbinom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{2^n}2^{n-1}=\frac12$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{2k}$, use the binomial theorem to compare $(1+1)^n$ to $(1+(-1))^n$.

Comment: im still unable to understand. I tried thinking of how i should be able to link the comparison between $(1+1)^n$ and $(1+(-1))^n$. Is it a long proof ? if so Ill try another way

Comment: (It's very short, don't worry.) What does the binomial theorem say about the two powers?

Comment: the power of one of the number is always smaller than the number of the term

Comment: the sum of the powers of a and b give us n  right ?

Comment: The binomial theorem says that $(1+1)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n\binom nk$, and it says that $(1+(-1))^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k\binom nk$. What happens if you add these two sums, letting things cancel.

Comment: we get the first and last term and the ones in between cancel each other

Answer (score 2):

The first $n-1$ flips in some sense don't matter at all, because the last flip will make the total number of heads even or odd with equal probability. So the probability is $0.5$.

Comment: +1. I always confuse this: Doesn't this assume that having even or odd number occurs with equal probability in the $n-1$-th toss? Which is actually what we want to show (does this need formally some kind of induction)? Excuse me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JimmyR. Let's say that, through some kind of magic, I can guarantee that the first $n-1$ tosses are all heads. Then you flip the final coin, which is heads or tails with equal probability. What happens?

Comment: thank you guys so much ! I appreciate the help. I was really confused thats true

Comment: @user387171 You're welcome! It's nice to be able to calculate complicated sums, but it's even nicer to avoid them altogether. :)

Comment: If the probability that I have tossed an odd (say) number of heads in the first $n-1$ tosses, is p (perhaps not equal to $\frac12$), then $$P(ev_n)=P(ev_n\mid od_{n-1} )P(od_{n-1})+P(ev_n\mid ev_{n-1})P(ev_{n-1})=\frac12p+\frac12(1-p)=\frac12$$ so no matter what it is $\frac12$. Ok, I see it know.

Comment: @JimmyR. Sure. To put it more simply, if the final toss is tails, then the total number of heads is not affected. If the final toss is heads, then the total number of heads switches from even to odd, or vice versa.